# How to read input in C with multiple numbers and char

Tags: c, input

I want to make a program in C, that calculates GPS coordinates do degrees. However, I have a trouble reading and input.

As an example, input will always be in this format `NUMBER CHAR NUMBER.NUMBER` (`49 E 54.2333` as an example).

I have tried this:

```c
    int d, m, s, f;
    char xy;

    printf("enter coordinates: ");
    scanf("%d %c %d.%d", &d, &xy, &s, &f);
```

but this seems to not work

```
Error C4996 'scanf': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using scanf_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.
```

I did put `scanf_s` and got "Debug Assertion failed" error

Comment: Did you actually read the error message and try what is suggested there? It tells you exactly what you might do to silence the error message

Comment: Are you sure, you want to use 2 integers instead of 1 double variable for the part after the single character? Why?

Comment: @Gerhardh I did, It just shuts down the program and "Debug Assertion failed" pops up

Comment: But you still show the old code? Please provide code and message that actually match. Either provide code with `scanf_s` and matching message or with the macro defined. How exactly did you replace? Please also show more context to your code. See [How-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for details

Comment: Did you just rename the function or did you read the [manual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/scanf-s-scanf-s-l-wscanf-s-wscanf-s-l?view=msvc-170)and also update parameters? Example to read 1 single `char`: `scanf_s("%c", &c, 1);`

Comment: The call `scanf("%d %c %d.%d", &d, &xy, &s, &f);` which you show is fine.  Just ignore Microsoft's nonsensical warning message.  Experience has shown that the allegedly-safer `scanf_s` is not, in fact, actually any safer: it just causes extra confusion, as you've discovered.

Comment: Add the line `#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS`, and the distracting warning message will go away, and you can go back to using plain `scanf`.  (And you'll only have to suffer `scanf`'s 17 stupid problems, not `scanf_s`'s additional ones.)

Comment: But do please change `scanf("%d %c %d.%d", &d, &xy, &s, &f);` to `if(scanf("%d %c %d.%d", &d, &xy, &s, &f) != 4) { printf("input error\n"); exit(1); }`.

Comment: Also, you're going to need to think about @Gerhardh's second suggestion.
If that last field is a true fraction, then with your code as it is,
you're going to have a hard time distinguishing between, say, 54.23, 54.023, and 54.0023.
(Also that last field is presumably minutes, not seconds.)